# How to override a function of another module in Drupal 7?

Tags: module, drupal-7

I have a module with a function:

```
function _somemodule_buddylist_online() {
    // do stuff
    return $users;
}
```

What I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
function _mymodule_that_overrides_buddylist_online($users) {
    // do stuff to users
    return $users;
}
```

So that when you call _somemodule_buddylist_online anywhere in the code, it will execute my function as well. Is this possible in anyway?

**UPDATE**

I basically want the calling of:

```
_somemodule_buddylist_online();
```

To result in the calling of:

```
$users = _somemodule_buddylist_online() ;
$users = _mymodule_that_overrides_buddylist_online($users);
return $users;
```

I want to accomplish this without editing the core module. It's an addon for an existing module, but I want to see if I can't make a viable solution without waiting for the necessary changes on the core module.

Answer (score 0):

Add weight to your module and that will take care of things or you can try using "hook_module_implements_alter"